# Magento-2: UPS shipping methods not appearing

Tags: magento2

I configured following developer UPS details under magento-2:

- Live Account: No
- Access License Number: ***
- Mode: Developer
- User ID:***
- Password: ***

However, UPS shipping methods not rendering on cart and checkout.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

UPS can be tested in dev or productin environment, not works in local environment.

Please provide the complete address at cart/checkout including country, state, zipcode e.g.:

USA
California
90014

It must work.

If zipcode is * then methods will not appear.

Thanks,